# go to new layout when click on imageview

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, imageview

how is it the function so  when i click on image view take me to an other layout ?!!

```
   ic01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://casidiablo.net"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

this code is not mine .. i found it here in this site which make you go to a site ... but what i need is to go to new layout

Comment: if you want to move to layout then Intent in = new Intent(activity.this,activity.class);
  startActivity(in);

Comment: New layout means? It will open in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
```

were you can use the above code inside onclick listener

Answer (score 1):

**res/layout/content_my.xml**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Within the MainActivity class, add the sendMessage() method stub shown below.
**java/com.mycompany.myfirstapp/MainActivity.java**

```
  public void sendMessage(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

And finally register SecondActivity in AndroidManifest.xml file. Dont forget to register.

Answer (score 1):

For information, you can go to an `activity` not to a `layout` because the layout is the `UI` of an `activity`, and to do that use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,DestinationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);`
```

and don't forget two add your activities in the '`manifest.xml` file.
For more information and details, check this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/how-to-switch-between-activities-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You mean open URL in app ?
You can use Webview in Android.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ActivityWebView.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

ActivityWebView.class

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://casidiablo.net");
```

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);